# Can't add multiple objects to List, Only one gets added

Tags: c#, collections

I am trying to add Cars to a List of Cars, but only one car ever seems to get added.
When I preform the InventoryCars() method, it only show one object.

What am I doing wrong?

```
namespace CarLot
{

    class Program
    {
        List<Car> CarList = new List<Car>();
        public static class GlobalVariables
        {
            public static int numberOfCars;
            public static int lotMax = 25;
            public static string userSelection;
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.Menu();
        }

        void InventoryCars()
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (var Car in CarList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Car);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something went Wrong!");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
            Menu();

        }

       void CreateNewPinto(bool isHybrid)
        {

            Pinto myPinto = new Pinto();
            if (isHybrid == true)
            {
                myPinto.hybrid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                myPinto.hybrid = false;
            }

            if (GlobalVariables.numberOfCars < GlobalVariables.lotMax)
            {
                GlobalVariables.numberOfCars++;
                CarList.Add(myPinto);
                Console.WriteLine("Pinto Created! Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Menu();

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The lot is full! Press any key to continue...");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Menu();
            }
        }

        static void CreateNewSemiTruck(bool isHybrid)
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.numberOfCars < GlobalVariables.lotMax)
            {
                GlobalVariables.numberOfCars++;
            }
            else
            {
                    Console.WriteLine("The lot is full!");
            }
        }

        static void CreateNewFunnyCar(bool isHybrid)
        {
            if (GlobalVariables.numberOfCars < GlobalVariables.lotMax)
            {
                GlobalVariables.numberOfCars++;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The lot is full!");
            }

        }

        static void DriveACar(int carNumber)
        {

        }

        static void HonkACar(int carNumber)
        {

        }

        static void FuelUpACar(int carNumber)
        {

        }

        static void DiscountACar(int carNumber)
        {

        }

        void Menu()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                           Lot Master 3000                                   |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                           ---------------                                   |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      1) Add Pinto                                                           |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      2) Add SemiTruck                                                       |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      3) Add FunnyCar                                                        |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      4) Add Pinto (Hybrid)                                                  |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      5) Add SemiTruck (Hybrid)                                              |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      6) Add FunnyCar (Hybrid)                                               |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      D) Drive a Car                                                         |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      F) Fuel Up a Car                                                       |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      H) Honk a Car                                                          |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      S) Mark car 'On Sale'                                                  |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      L) List all Cars on Lot                                                |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("|      0) Exit Program                                                        |");
            Console.WriteLine("|                                                                             |");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            Console.Write("Enter Selection: ");
            GlobalVariables.userSelection = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

            if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "0")
            {
                System.Environment.Exit(0);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "1")
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                p.CreateNewPinto(false);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "2")
            {
                CreateNewSemiTruck(false);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "3")
            {
                CreateNewFunnyCar(false);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "4")
            {
                Program p = new Program();
                p.CreateNewPinto(true);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "5")
            {
                CreateNewSemiTruck(true);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "6")
            {
                CreateNewFunnyCar(true);
            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "D")
            {

            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "F")
            {

            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "H")
            {

            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "S")
            {

            }
            else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "L")
            {
               InventoryCars();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Selection! Enter any key to continue....");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Menu();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a [switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) case for the user selection string. As for your question, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: Is a switch case more effecient?

Comment: @CryptoJones For just a few items, the difference is small. If you have many items you should definitely use a switch. Switch is also more readable in my opinion.

Comment: What line would I add the breakpoint to? Sorry I have never used break points before.

Comment: Nobody here answered the question which is more important.

Comment: Also, why are people downvoting this question? Did I ask it incorrectly somehow?

Comment: As I loop through it is showing that there is only one object in the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the you keep doing

```
Program p = new Program();
```

and you're doing this inside `Menu()` method. Inside the `Menu()` method you're already in the scope of `Program` so you just need to call the method. e.g.:

```
else if (GlobalVariables.userSelection == "1")
{
    CreateNewPinto(false);
}
```

remove the creating of new instance of Program and all will be OK.

Good luck

Comment: When I do that it complains about "Object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property."

Comment: CryptoJones - di you copy paste the code he gave above? If you had done this then all you have to do is remove the lines of "Program p = new Program();" and the "p." inside the if statements of "1" and "4". Try again and tell me how it goes. And please remove the "-1" you gave me

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. I removed the 'Program p = new Program();' from the main function, not the CreatePinto(); function as you suggested.

When I did what you suggested my list now contained all the items! 

Thank You Shahar Eldad!